# Using Bing map api 7 how to animate a pushpin from one set of coordinates to another?

Tags: javascript, gis, bing-maps

Using Bing maps api 7 and JavaScript I want to add a Pushpin to a map then have it move at a steady pace in a straight line to a new set of coordinates.

I want the Pushpin to be able to move to one place and then stop and wait for new coordinates. When it gets new coordinates from the rest service it will move to the new coordinates in the same way.

I have looked over the bing maps documentation trying to find an answer to my question with no success... I would prefer to do everything using the bing maps api and not have to add a third party library if possible. If it is not possible then I am open to third party library suggestions.

here is how I add a Pushpin

```
    map.entities.push(new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(lat, lon), {
        text: name,
        visible: true,
        textOffset: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(0, 5)
    }));
```

Now that I have a Pushpin on my map how do I animate it to another set of coordinates. How?

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial, it might help you: https://blogs.bing.com/maps/2014/08/07/bring-your-maps-to-life-creating-animations-with-bing-maps-javascript/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exact scenario has been documented in a blog post by the Bing Maps team here: https://blogs.bing.com/maps/2014/08/07/bring-your-maps-to-life-creating-animations-with-bing-maps-javascript/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11109238)

Comment: I beg to differ. By referring the user to the original source, in this case the official source for all Bing Maps related information, not only do they get the answer they are looking for, but they are also directed to a resource filled with information which the likely will find useful. I'm one of the top forum moderators on MSDN and have been for nearly a decade. I have tried a lot of different approaches and found that this approach helps the developer the most.

Comment: This points to an official blog post from Microsoft on how to do exactly what the author is asking. I should know, I'm on the Bing Maps team and spend most of my time managing the developer community.